# Browsers will not search, but if i use specific url's I can connect to a website

Tags: networking

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I have internet connection and it is working.
In multiple browsers I can type in specific URL's and the websites will populate
--however when i try to search in these browsers (ex. Pictures of tree's) i will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

So software updater was throwing an error. I reviewed what software's were updating, closed software updater, and rebooted my PC.

Now it works again. I'm trying to better my understanding of Linux, however it is likely i have to purge some repositories off of my PC.